# What is the mistake in my derivation of cosine

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

In a triangle $ABC$ let's let $\overrightarrow{a}=\text{vector }\overrightarrow{BC}$, let $\overrightarrow{b}=\text{vector }\overrightarrow{CA}$, and let $\overrightarrow{c}=\text{vector }\overrightarrow{BA}$,. Let's let $\gamma=\text{angle }ACB$.

Then;

$$\overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}$$

$$\overrightarrow{c}\cdot\overrightarrow{c}=\left(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\right)\cdot\left(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\right)$$

$$\overrightarrow{c}\cdot\overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}+2\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}$$

$$|c|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2+2|a||b|\cos(\gamma)$$

But, the cosine law says: $|c|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|\cos(\gamma)$.

So I guess I made a mistake somewhere in the process. What was my mistake?

Comment: TO jump on a bandwagon late:  Geometric interpretation of $a + b$ to place the *vertex* of $b$ onto the *endpoint* of $a$ the resulting angle is $\angle ABC$.  Geometric interpretation of $a\cdot b$ is place the *vertices* of $a$ and $b$ together.  In our figure this would involve drawing a point $D$ so that $BD=CA$ and $\overline {BD}$ is parallel to $\overline {CA}$ and the vector $BD$ will, being same magnitude and parallel, to $CA$ be the same vector(?). So the angle of $a\cdot b$ will be $\angle CBD$ which is supplimentary to $\angle BCA$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gamma$ is defined to be angle $ACB$, then $\gamma$ is not the angle between vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$. The angle between them will be $180^{\circ}-\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Because the angle ACB should be the angle formed by vector CA and CB instead of vector CA and vector BC, that was where you made the mistake.

Comment: you can try to graph the angle between vector CA and CB, also the angle between vector CA and BC, they will be supplementary to each other, only one of them fit in the original triangle， that is why order matters